# How to pass data back to parent window?

Tags: javascript, html

I found a link that shows how to send parameters back to the opener browser window. But it works only with `window.showmodal()`. There should be an easy way to do the same if I use `window.open()` right?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using window.open, you can call a function in the parent window and pass in pararmeters to that function.

Do this in child page javascript

```
var x="hello";//parameter I want to pass to the parent
window.opener.ParentPageFunctionName(x);
```

Comment: No longer works with Chrome either -- you can't dive down into details of the opening window, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You want the parent property.  See this for details:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp