# Techniques to pass data from one open window to another open window (HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have two open webpages. The first one is a form, and the other one is list of products. What I want to do is when I click a product on the second webpage, the data (name, description etc.) will be send to the first page. The sent data will be posted on a textarea in the first page. Then the form will be send to email.

What are the ways to do this? I thought of storing data to cookies, but I don't know how the first page will detect if there will be new values for cookies. What are other possible ways to this?

Comment: Are windows for "two open webpages" related in some way (i.e. opener or parent)?

Comment: Can you please provide some source code? This will help assist in understanding your question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The first page is a Form that has a "Product" link. when the link is click, the new webpage will appear (that is the second webpage that has the list of products). When a product is click, it will pass the information (name, desc etc.) to the first webpage and it will be loaded on a textarea

Comment: As @Tymetakr said on Earth code provides easier to understand information than words... Consider posting at least click handler that opens new window...

Comment: Note that this may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804794/how-to-pass-data-back-to-parent-window (or some other question) depending on what you use.